# Is migration required in a Django application?

Tags: python, django

I want to use Django with nothing but legacy databases.  Lots of them.  I want to use raw SQL in my model(s).

Do I need migration to make Django function properly?  I don't want to use migration because I don't want Django to do anything with or to my databases.  I prefer to use SQL and return data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use migrations.

(Also, it may be relevant to note that you *can* use raw SQL, but Django will still set up some things for you so you can use its ORM, even with legacy databases. But migrations are not one of these things it does for you.)

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials that do not use any of the magic migrate and admin features?  All I'm wanting is MVC, but all under my control (as much as possible).

Comment: @johnny: Just don't create any migrations, and don't install the admin app. (Although, if you're not going to use most or any of Django's core features, you might be better off with another framework like Flask.)

Comment: I thought of that but flask is at 0.10.1.  That does not sound "battle tested," and I wasn't sure it could handle really big sites.

Comment: @johnny: The version number doesn't increment much, but it's in use at a number of places. The place I work uses it for a pretty big web app.

Answer (score 2):

Migrations are not required. They can be useful for creating and tracking database changes via code, but Django applications will run properly without them.

Comment: Am I circumventing the real reason for using Django in the first place?

Comment: Not at all. Migrations are a small subset of the features offered. In fact, there was a time that Django did not include migration functionality at all--it had to be added via a package called 'South.'

Comment: As of today (Jan, 2015), migrations are a very recent feature (added at version 1.7 I believe). If you prefer SQLAlchemy over Django's ORM you may consider Flask. If you don't like ORMs at all, I think you should learn to like them - no way I would recommend string interpolation/composition for SQL queries.

Comment: @PauloScardine ORM vs not is an old debate, especially here on SO.  I really prefer SQL, no flame intended.  The hard part now is to find a tutorial that puts it all together without migrate.

Comment: @johnny indeed it is a matter of taste, and I respect yours. For me, since `sqlalchemy.sql` maps 1:1 to raw SQL while adding a lot of security and intelligence,  I can't go back to strings.

Comment: @johnny try the tutorial for version Django 1.6 (at least the part about the database).